# How to configure latest nodejs in OpenShift?

Tags: node.js, openshift

Today OpenShift supports nodejs version 4, my application in on 6.9.4 LTS.
Is it possible to override default settings and install latest nodejs in OpenShift cartridge?

I am aware about this [custom cartridge](https://github.com/icflorescu/openshift-cartridge-nodejs), my question is on how we could install latest nodejs?

Comment: Which version of OpenShift are you using? V2 uses cartridges, but V3 is different and uses S2I (source-to-image) builders based around Docker.

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton I am using V2 (catridges)

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned [this docuentation about Marker"](https://developers.openshift.com/languages/nodejs/markers.html) you can specify your NodeJS version by creating a file named NODEJS_VERSION and put your version you needed inside it.

Of course you have to clone it first via git on address specified on your Application setting (called "Source Code" on upper right corner). 
`git push` it would trigger a build and deploy